# using MVC 2 instead of MVC1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, assemblies

Hi 
I was trying to setup atomsite, i dont have MVC 1 on my system, so i changed it to MVC 2
I got his error:

how do I fix it?

```
 Error  30  Assembly 'AtomSite.WebCore, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' c:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\AtomSite 1.4.0.0 Source\WebCore\bin\AtomSite.WebCore.dll   OpenIdPlugin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error it looks like you do have MVC 1 installed, and thats what you're referencing.  The AtomSite.WebCore assembly appears to require MVC 2, but the version of System.Web.Mvc that you've referenced in the project is 1.0.

Comment: I changed all of them already to mvc 2, that's why this happening, if i have mvc 1 , this will not be a problem

Comment: u r right. i changed all the places except one place, i will mark your answer after 7 minutyes